# .NET Chart Controls in Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox

Tags: sandbox-solution, web, chart, .net

I'm trying to use the .NET Chart Controls in my Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox solution. I have downloaded and installed the MSChart for .NET 3.5 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422.

Does anyone know if the .NET Chart Controls are supported in Sharepoint 2010 Sandbox solutions?

I tried to find examples and I can only find examples for Sharepoint 2010 (not Sandbox) and in these you need to add assembly references in you web.config file, which is not possible in Sandbox. This is an example of using .NET Chart in Sharepoint [http://mosshowto.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/asp-net-chart-control-sharepoint.html](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422).

I know it's possible to add a web part containing a chart but a requirement for the solution is that it's all done from code in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's NOT possible to use MSChart for .NET 3.5 in a Sandbox solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate chart in sandbox solution then Jquery is best option for that 
See this link for google chart jquery plugin

http://www.maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/

Comment: I know that is an solution but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

We have implemented the .Net 3.5 Chart Control in a SharePoint Visual Web Part and it is working absolutely fine. May I know what Project Template have you created to implement the .Net Chart Control in it?

Implement the .Net 3.5 Chart Control in SharePoint Visual Web Part and it will work. SharePoint Visual Web Parts are always deployed as Farm Solution because the reason is the visual web part project uses an ASP.NET user control, which must be deployed to the “~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES” folder in the SharePoint hive. In order to access this folder, the web part needs to have farm permissions.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: Guess you didn't see where he mentioned "Sandbox-Solution" in the question?

Comment: Hi Ryan, i hope u read my reply.. I have asked him a question so that I can provide him with an answer.

Comment: Zakir - the orig question specifically asked how to do charting with a sandbox compatible web part. You've given him an answer that will not work in the sandbox. What have I misunderstood?